# Exporting highlighted source code to pdf in Org-Mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, python, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to export some python code with syntax highlighted to a pdf, from org-mode. Even though I can export to html without any issues I could not find a way to export it to pdf.

n.b. I'm using spacemacs but also tried without success with vanilla emacs.

Answer (score 11):

Hey [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20841/18033) answer solved my similar problem. A bit late but I had the same issue today.

As mentioned, I add the following code snipped to my `.spacemacs`/`.emacs` config:

```
(require 'org)
(require 'ox-latex)
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "minted"))
(setq org-latex-listings 'minted) 

(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))

(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)

(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((R . t)
   (latex . t)))
```

To use Minted, you need to install the companion program `pygments`. You can do this with `pip install pygments`.