# Export code blocks in org-mode with minted environment

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

After inspecting the LaTeX generated for my org-mode file, I figured out that the code blocks are exported with the `verbatim` environment. Are there any way to tell org-mode to export code blocks using the `minted` environment for the appropriated language?

Comment: possibly see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20839/exporting-code-blocks-to-pdf-via-latex/20841#20841

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to tell Org to

1. Use minted for listings
2. Include minted in the default package list
3. Change the compilation switches to accommodate for minted:

```
(setq org-latex-listings 'minted
      org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "minted"))
      org-latex-pdf-process
      '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```