# Export org-mode code blocks with minted style

Tags: org-mode, org-export, syntax-highlighting, style

I am trying to export org-mode source blocks to pdf via Latex and I use minted to get syntax highlighting. My org file looks like this:

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %% For unicode chars

#+latex_header: \usepackage{minted}                                              
#+latex_header: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+latex_header: \usemintedstyle{monokai}    %% sets default for all source-code blocks
#+latex_header: \definecolor{dark}{HTML}{272822}   %% custom colour for background

#+attr_latex: :options bgcolor=dark
#+BEGIN_SRC bash -i
    rosrun rosbag topic_renamer.py <in topic> <in bag> <out topic> <out bag>
#+END_SRC
```

I read on [this latex thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374043/minted-color-themes-display-improper-colors), that I have to manually specify the background colour, which is why I use that additional `#+attr_latex:` specifying `bgcolor`. That definitely does seem to help, but I cannot get the bash language to be correctly coloured. I get black text on the manually applied `dark` background:

[image: dark text]

So it seems the colour of the text is somehow affected by the `bgcolor` I manually apply to the source-block.

If I change the language, e.g. to `c`, I get something more like what I expect (which also happens to look pretty cool!):

```
#+attr_latex: :options bgcolor=dark
#+BEGIN_SRC c -i
    rosrun rosbag topic_renamer.py <in topic> <in bag> <out topic> <out bag>
#+END_SRC
```

[image: light text as expected]

trying to set the style manually for the source-block also doesn't seem to help. Using this:

```
#+attr_latex: :options style=monokai, bgcolor=dark
#+BEGIN_SRC bash -i
    rosrun rosbag topic_renamer.py <in topic> <in bag> <out topic> <out bag>
#+END_SRC
```

makes no difference, and I get the same as above, without the style option:

[image: dark text again]

I can see in the generated `tex` files that options are being passed correctly to the minted block:

```
\begin{minted}[breaklines=true,breakanywhere=true,bgcolor=dark]{shell}
    rosrun rosbag topic_renamer.py <in topic> <in bag> <out topic> <out bag>
\end{minted}
```

---

I have the following setup in my init file:

```
(setq org-latex-listings 'minted
    org-latex-packages-alist '(("newfloat" "minted"))
    org-latex-pdf-process
    '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
      "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

which [was taken from here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/export-code-blocks-in-org-mode-with-minted-environment).

I have tried looking in the list of language names to language modes (a mapping) that org-mode maintains, and see that bash was there, I also added `(shell shell)` so the name "shell" is mapped the `shell-mode`.
Otherwise I don't really know where to start

**EDIT:**

Output when editing the `.tex` file and compiling in terminal:

```
\begin{minted}[style=monokai,bgcolor=dark]{bash}
  #!/usr/bin/bash
  for (( i=0; i != 10; i=i+1)); do
  echo $i
  done
\end{minted}
```

[image: dark text]

some text remains dark and un-readable

Comment: I do not use `minted` nor `pygments`. Nevertheless from http://pygments.org/demo/ I would have expected `bash` as language specifier for the `minted` LaTeX environment but you get `shell` which is not present in the `Select a lexer` box at http://pygments.org/demo/. Maybe the mapping of `bash` source blocks to `shell` source blocks is the actual problem. Try to replace `shell` by `bash` in the LaTeX source file and to run `pdflatex` for that file.

Comment: I have tried both of them, to no avail. I also added special mappings between all combinations I thought reasonable via `org-latex-listings-langs`, but this also didn't help anything. As the `tex` file itself (when altered manually) isn't producing the expected output, I am starting to think the problem lies with tex/minted/pygments - not org-mode.

Comment: Use an example which should have a prominent highlighting such as [the linked bash script](http://pygments.org/demo/6754720/) and try to get that highlighting with LaTeX.

Comment: It looks like LaTeX shell-escape and python are working since you get highlighting for the C example. Maybe you should also try an extended C example, for an instance a [helloWorld.c code](http://pygments.org/demo/6754722/).

Comment: I tried them, compiling the `tex` file from terminal, and the style is not taken... I have `\usemintedstyle{monokai}` i.e. a dark theme in the pre-amble, however teh background is light and the text is dark. If I then force a dark background, the font colours remain the same as before, but it doesn't match the example from the pygments demo (see the added picture in my edit above). It is better than what org-mode manages, but still not right. I tried both `bash` and `shell` as languages, both giving that same result.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem with some text remaining unstyled. In order to set that color to a more readable text use the following:
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\color{Text}}

Read more here: https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/72#issuecomment-92422746